# how to send email using codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

```
 public function reset()
 {
    $config=array(
        'protocol'=> 'smtp',
        'smtp_host'=> 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_user'=> 'xxxxx',
        'smtp_pass'=> 'xxxxx',
        'smtp_port'=> 465,
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


    $this->email->from('abc@gmail.com','abc');
    $this->email->to('abc@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Password Reset');
    $this->email->message('U have request new password, Here is the new password:');

    if( $this->email->send())
    {
        echo('mail is send successfully');
    }
    else
    {
        echo("Error in Email sending");
    }
    // redirect('http://localhost/p_test/index.php/login/forget');
}
```

It show the following error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
Error in Email sending
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
protocol = smtp
smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
smtp_crypto = ssl
smtp_user = your user
smtp_pass = your pass
```

This is how I send mails using Gmail in CodeIgniter.